# How to hide tooltips on menuItem's in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, android-bottomnav

How to hide tooltips on menuItem's in BottomNavigationView ? Now i can't get how to control this behaviour. I'm already tried something like this:

```
    for (item in vBottomNavigation.children) {
        TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(item, null)
    }
```

or

```
 TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(vBottomNavigation, null)
```

or finally

```
   vBottomNavigation.setOnLongClickListener {
        true
    }
```

But nothing worked, also i tried set tooltipText in menu resources to @null or empty string, but anyway i see tooltips on long press on bottom menu items.

I want to control visibility of tooltips on the bottomnavigation view. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to show this tooltip on long click, you can override **BottomNavigationItemView**'s long click behavior by setting OnLongClickListener to the menu items, like the code below(I tried this solution with BottomNavigationView from material components with the following version: `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04`)
:

```
bottomNavigation.menu.forEach {
  val view = bottomNavigation.findViewById<View>(it.itemId)
  view.setOnLongClickListener {
    // your logic here
    true
  }
}
```

Note that this tooltip behavior is set to **each BottomNavigationItemView** that BottomNavigationView inflates on its constructor, so the tooltip behavior is not set to BottomNavigationView itself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there **isn't** a method to show/hide the tooltip.
You can set the `tooltipText` with:

- `TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(item,"...")`
- `bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setTooltipText("...")`

However in the `BottomNavigationView` there is this code:

```
CharSequence tooltipText = !TextUtils.isEmpty(itemData.getTooltipText())
    ? itemData.getTooltipText()
    : itemData.getTitle();
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(this, tooltipText);
```

If your tooltip is empty or `""` the **title** will be displayed.